# addOnSuccessListener always returns null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

im trying to read data from my firebase database using a addOnSuccessListener. However i managed to recevice the values ones, but now, i always get null returned. I don't understand why. Any help is appreciated

Main Activity:

```
private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            
        //Read Users
        database = Firebase.database.reference

        var test : DataSnapshot

        database.child("User").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.i("firebase", "Got value ${it.value}")
        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
       }
```

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gVbB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUqoo.png)

[nullpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c11er.png)
[updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjS8e.png)

I've tried changing the child to ("Groups") but the same thing happens

Comment: So is it throwing a NullPointerException at the first log call above? What is the point of that `test` variable? You may be running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o), but not enough of your code is shown to be sure.

Comment: The test variable is just null, i also noticed, i was able to write to the database before with database.child("User").push().setValue(value). But now thoose values dosnt get stored either

Comment: I don't see where `test` is written to anywhere in the code above. And what does it have to do with the code in your success listener? You added a screen shot showing it to be null in the debugger, but where is your breakpoint?

Comment: It just passes both cases, addOnSuccessListener and addOnFailureListener, in debug mode

Comment: Need to see the actual code where you set the value of `test`, but from what you're describing, it sounds like the issue I linked in my comment above.

Comment: Oh wait im stupid, yeah you are right, for some reason i thought test was linked to it

Comment: Im gonna check that post you linked, but it yeah, i set test = it however it still returns null

Comment: You were right, its in debug mode that i dont get values. But when i run it i get it. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: You're welcome. Usually, there would be no point in declaring that `test` variable outside of your listener, because it cannot be practically used from outside the listener. Anything you need to do with the listener results needs to be done inside the listener.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabase).